# HTML5 accesskey key attribute not working for hidden element

Tags: html

I am working on a full blown ajax based web application and i want it to feel like a desktop application by leveraging HTML5 `accesskey` attribute to serve as shortcut keys. I noticed for elements in a container whose css `display` attribute is set to `none` doesnt work. e.g

```
//this example does not work
<div style="display:none;">
   <a accesskey="s" href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stackoverflow</a>
</div>
```

//This works fine

```
<a accesskey="f" href="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
```

Is there a way to get the first example to work. I suspect on page load, due to the fact the first anchor tag is in a hidden container, accesskey doesnt bind. This is also true for html 5 `required` attribute for input element. I tried to inspect my DOM but there was no errors on the console. how can i fix this

Comment: Works for me. Which browser are you testing on?

Comment: google chrome browser